# How To fix Sql Profiler Error 2-Abort for RPC completed event

Tags: sql-server, performance, timeout, sql-server-profiler

When I am executing SP in sql server, it is executing with in 3 seconds.
But when accessed through application it is throwing a time-out exception.
To analyse that, used sql profiler . In that, found an error with **2-abort** for **RPC completed** event.

Any one have any idea how to fix this?